# How to use QDataWidgetMapper in Qt or PyQt?

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, model-view-controller, pyqt

I can find some examples of how to use standard model with standard view.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/modelview.html

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-simplewidgetmapper-example.html

but I just can not find ONE example of how to use `QAbstractModel` make my own `model` and to use it on my own `view/widget`.

After I update the model the stand view will update but not my own view.[image: run result]

Full code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from  PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QLabel, QDataWidgetMapper,
                              QLineEdit, QApplication, QGridLayout)
from PyQt5.QtCore import QAbstractListModel, Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QListView


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, model, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)

        self.model = model

        # Set up the widgets.
        nameLabel = QLabel("Na&me:")
        nameEdit = QLineEdit()

        # Set up the mapper.
        self.mapper = QDataWidgetMapper(self)
        self.mapper.setModel(self.model)
        self.mapper.addMapping(nameEdit, 0)

        layout = QGridLayout()
        layout.addWidget(nameLabel, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        layout.addWidget(nameEdit, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.mapper.toFirst()


class MyModel(QAbstractListModel):
    def __init__(self, status=[], parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.status = status

    def rowCount(self, index_parent=None, *args, **kwargs):
        return len(self.status)

    def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole, parent=None):
        if not index.isValid():
            return None
        row = index.row()
        if row == 0:
            print(index)
            if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
                return self.status[row]
            elif role == Qt.EditRole:  # if it's editing mode, return value for editing

                return self.status[row]

    def flags(self, index):
        return Qt.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.ItemIsEditable

    def setData(self, index, value='', role=Qt.EditRole):
        row = index.row()

        if role == Qt.EditRole:
            self.status[row] = value
            self.dataChanged.emit(index, index)  # inform the other view to request new data
            return True
        else:
            return False


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    myModel_on_mywindow = MyModel([1, 2, 3])
    mywindow = Window(myModel_on_mywindow)
    mywindow.setWindowTitle('myModel_on_mywindow')
    mywindow.show()
    myModel_on_mywindow.status[0] = 2

    myModel_on_qlistview = MyModel([1, 2, 3])
    qlistview = QListView()
    qlistview.show()
    qlistview.setModel(myModel_on_qlistview)
    qlistview.setWindowTitle('myModel_on_qlistview')

    myModel_on_qlistview.status[0] = 2

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: What about [Model Subclassing Reference](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html#model-subclassing-reference) and [QAbstractItemModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html) ?

Comment: @Miki Thanks. I know how to make a customised model. but I do not know how to use it on my widget.

Comment: How about now? @ekhumoro

Comment: @Miki Can't I use QDataWidgetMapper like this: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-simplewidgetmapper-example.html

Comment: @Miki If I use `QListView` I will need a lot of them, and a lot of models

Comment: Yeah, sorry. Qlistview stuff was a bad advice... However, I can't understand why the approach of the example doesn't fit your needs

Comment: It often helps to start with a stock model to ensure that the rest of the code works, and only then switch to a custom model.

Comment: Because the model changes will not show on my own view. @Miki

Comment: @KubaOber I just can not understand how it work inside.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your custom model needs to override some functions of the abstract model, depending on which one you subclass. This is a small example for subclassing the QAbstractListModel. You can read more about this in the Qt documentation: [QAbstractListModel Details](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractlistmodel.html#details)

```
class MyModel(QAbstractListModel):
    def __init__(parent=None):
        QAbstractListModel.__init__(parent)
        self.content = []  # holds the data, you want to present

    def rowCount(index):
        return len(self.content)
    # This defines what the view should present at given index
    def data(index, role):
        if index.isValid() and role == Qt.DisplayRole):
            dataElement = self.content[index.row()]
            if index.colum() == 0:
                return dataElement.someBoolField
            if index.colum() == 1:
                return dataElement.someIntField
            # ...
        }
        return QVariant()  # this is like returning nothing
    }
    # If your items should be editable. Automatically called, when user changes the item.
    def setData(index, value, role):
        if index.isValid():
            dataElement = self.content[index.row()].get()
            if index.column() == 0:
                return dataElement.tryToSetBoolField(value.toBool())
            if index.column() == 1:
                return dataElement.tryToSetIntField(value.toInt())
            # ...
        }
        return True
    }
};

# connecting your view with your model
model = MyModel()
myView = QTreeView()  # or something else
myView.setModel(model)
```

**EDIT**

To update your view when using a custom Model in combination with a QDataMapper, call setCurrentIndex(changedIndex) or its wrappers after changing the model, like so in your case:

```
myModel_on_mywindow.status[0] = 2
myModel.mapper.toFirst()
```

The Qt documentation on QDataMapper mentions this in the detailed description:

> The navigational functions toFirst(), toNext(), toPrevious(), toLast() and setCurrentIndex() can be used to navigate in the model **and update the widgets with contents from the model**.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have done this and it works. The problem here is how to apply it to my widget, like this:class BicMainWindow(QWidget, Ui_Form):

Comment: Sorry for the delayed answer. I edited my answer to solve your problem. Just call `setCurrentIndex()` or its wrappers after changing your model.

Comment: @x squared Thank you very much for your answer. I have edited my question. I am sorry it's not very clear at beginning. I don't know should I ask a new question or still use this one. You can run my code you will find the problem.

Comment: I've seen the addition and added information at the end of my answer. Did that not solve your updating problem?

Comment: @x squared It's strange. It did solve my problem. Why? Will it create another group of data?

Comment: From the documentation it reads like the functions force the view to update so that the correct content is displayed at the given index